# Which script for an audio sharing site?

Tags: looking-for-a-script, audio

I am going to build an audio sharing site. I am familiar with Drupal but I hope there are some more 'Specialized' CMS/Script for this purpose, whatever that is not ASP-based.

So please suggest best candidates. It is OK if it is commercial, provided that it is proven to be robust.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[There some vague bits in this; sorry, but I've never looked at it specifically for audio purposes.]
The most recent/modern media management-specific app I know of is [MediaCore](http://opensource.mediacore.com/), which is based on Python and MySQl.

You'll note immediately that it's pitched as a video platform, but because it uses a pluggable system for how the media is actually output(eg. it can use JWPlayer, Flowplayer, SublimeVideo, etc.) there's no real reason it can't be used for audio, and people [already do](http://opensource.mediacore.com/community/topic/audio-mp3-problem-with-html5-players-in-beta3). It might be worth a look.

Comment: Actually MediaCore is an elegant candidate which I'd forgotten to consider. First it is Python, secondly MC is made upon Pylons, one of the best Python framework of all times. Many thanks